# Recursive function to make a^b

Tags: python

My recursive function doesn't seem to be working - it’s supposed to take parameters `a` and `b` and return
`a^b`.

Here it is:

```
def power(a, b):
       If b == 0:
               return
       return a * power(a,  b-1)
power(2,  3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Base case return statement is null. You should return 1 (since `a^0 = 1` for `a != 0`).

```
if b == 0:
    return 1
```

You might want to handle the case for `a = 0` separately though, since `0^0` is mathematically undefined:

```
if a == 0:
    if b > 0:
        return 0
    else
        # raise an exception here?
```

Comment: @Florian.C this is a [debated topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero), and taking the result to be 0 is "equally correct" - the math people don't like that...

Answer (score 0):

```
def power(a, b):
   if b == 0:
      return 1;
   return a * power(a,  b - 1);
```